# Get best hit first

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table department with a columns SearchKeysName and BOLD_ID. Bold_ID is just a number for identification of row.
It contains data like this:

```
Bold_ID; SearchKeysName
1005; [12212][FALKENBERG][32-1][][523451]
1000; [124132][AB CD BYGG][GÖTEBORG][124132-1][][CD-BYGG CO][556435979101]
```

To search data I have SQL like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 BOLD_ID FROM Department UPPER(SearchKeysName) LIKE '%\[%32-1%]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

In this case I searched for 32-1 so it will pick the rows above.
What I want is to make sure the exact hit is placed on top of the result.
Like this

```
1000
1005
```

This is of course a simplified example. In reality there are thousands of rows so I can miss the first line with 32-1 as there are many others that and with this string when search string is short.

Only idea I have so far is to make 2 searches.
One with

```
LIKE '%\[32-1]%'
```

If that don't find anything then try more generic like above.

**EDIT**
Now tried this:

```
SELECT distinct TOP 100 DEPARTMENT.BOLD_ID
from Department 
where upper(SearchKeysName) like '%\[%32-1%]%' ESCAPE '\'
order by case when SearchKeysName like '%\[32-1]%' ESCAPE '\' then 0 else 1 end
```

And got this

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Comment: It seems your issue is really down to combining multiple atomic data elements in a single column. you probably need two unioned queries here.

Comment: Yes that is not my design. But I guess it is a compromise to be able to search many things at once.

Comment: Is the value you are searching for always to be found at the end of the "segment" or is something like `[432-123]` possible?

Comment: Delimited data in single column is pretty much always the wrong schema design. This cries out for an additional table.

Comment: Yes I know the design is ugly. It was done long time ago and none in the team dared to change it as it works decently. About [432-123]. It is possible but not likely.
After minus char there is usually only 1 or 2 numbers

Comment: Btw I cannot count on that user search numbers. It can be FALKENBERG. In that case all rows that contains [FALKENBERG] should be on the top of the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `case` *expression* to get exact hit rows first:

```
order by case when SearchKeysName like '%\[32-1]%' ESCAPE '\' then 0 else 1 end, Bold_ID
```

To get distinct BOLD_ID's, do a `GROUP BY`, to sort a BOLD_ID with an exact match first (even if it also has a non-exact match):

```
SELECT TOP 100 BOLD_ID
from Department 
where SearchKeysName like '%\[%32-1%]%' ESCAPE '\'
group by BOLD_ID
order by min(case when SearchKeysName like '%\[32-1]%' ESCAPE '\' then 0 else 1 end),
         BOLD_ID
```